# Out of storage issue with hard drive

Tags: storage

I am using a apple computer. I show I have a hard drive connected with plenty of space but I am getting low space notifications.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your root partition (denoted as `/`) has only 1.5 GB available (out of 26.8 GB).

If you want to install a lot of apps in Ubuntu, you need at least 50 GB or so.

You will have to reinstall Ubuntu to a bigger partition.
You can shrink the partition your drive during the system installation. Don't forget to take a backup.